# Inverse Function: f(x) = (3+4x)/4x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, proof-verification, inverse-function

Find the inverse of the function:

$$\ f(x)=  \frac{3+4x}{x−1}$$

My answer:

$$\ =  \frac{3}{4x−4}$$

I have been informed that my answer is incorrect.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Can you show us how you got to this answer though ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding the inverse function, let's start off of the basic expression : $$y=f(x) \Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(y) = x \Rightarrow y = f^{-1}(x)$$

So :

$$y = \frac{3+4x}{x-1} \Leftrightarrow y(x-1) = 3+4x \Leftrightarrow yx - y - 3 - 4x = 0 \Leftrightarrow(y-4)x-y-3=0 $$

$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$(y-4)x = y+3 \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{y+3}{y-4}$$

which stands for $y-4 \neq 0$ but also take into account that $x \neq 1$ from the initial domain of $f$.

Thus, the inverse is :

$$g(x) = f^{-1}(x) = \frac{x+3}{x-4}, \space x\neq4, x\neq 1$$

Comment: Since $f(x) = \frac{3 + 4x}{x - 1} = 4 + \frac{7}{x - 1}$, then its domain is $\text{Dom}_f = (-\infty, 1) \cup (1, \infty)$ and its range is $\text{Ran}_f = (-\infty, 4) \cup (4, \infty)$.  Hence, the domain of $f^{-1}$ is $\text{Dom}_{f^{-1}} = (-\infty, 4) \cup (4, \infty)$ and its range is $\text{Ran}_{f^{-1}} = (-\infty, 1) \cup (1, \infty)$.  If $x \neq 1$ in the domain of $f$, then $y \neq 1$ in the range of $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{3+4x}{x-1}=y\implies xy-y-4x=3\implies x(y-4)=y+3\implies$$

$$x=\frac{y+3}{y-4}$$

and thus the inverse function is

$$g(x)=\frac{x+3}{x-4}$$

Check it.

Comment: Don't forget the domain limitations which are an important part of inversing.

Comment: @Rebellos That's for the OP to complete.